# How to create a custom directory layout in Maven?

Tags: java, maven

I want to create a custom directory layout in maven . I only want the src/test/java and resource and want 2 other folders , so that my file in the other folder could call the folder in src/test/java .

Right now if I try to create and run such structure , classpath error is obtained as the program cannot move to the class present in src/test/java .

I could put all my packages and files in src/test/java but I want different folders to work on.

So that gives us the classpath error.[![In the image i am trying to call the Login_AUT1 which is in the scr/test/java through the launcher class which is in the communication folder . 
So basically what happens is the launcher calls the class inside the Login_AUT1 method.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBio8.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBio8.png)
Thanks

Comment: Please add your expected structure and actual error trace

Comment: First why do you think you need a custom directory layout? I have my doubts about that...better use the conventions..Apart from that src/test/java and src/test/resources is default..In src/test/java belongs all test code but NO production code...

Comment: Why do you use Maven then? Maven's whole point is to force a standard directory structure. Use gradle or ivy.

Answer (score 1):

You could add these two folders as test sources folders by using the `add-test-source` goal of the [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html).

Here is an example from the [documentation](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html) :

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>add-test-source</id>
            <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-test-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>some directory</source>
                ...
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Replace :

```
 <sources>
     <source>some directory</source>
                    ...
 </sources>
```

by your folders :

```
 <sources>
     <source>folderFoo</source>
     <source>folderBar</source>
 </sources>
```